# When would one use factorials in probability?

Tags: probability

What should a question say so that you know you must use factorials to solve it?

Would the word distinguishable be a keyword?

Comment: Well, if I have $n$ indistinguishable balls, I can arrange them in a row in one way only. But if they are distinguishable, I can do so in $n!$ ways.

Comment: @Peter : I've seen a question answered with factorial and nCr . So what's the difference between them? When should I use factorial and when should I switch to nCr? I know nPr is for when order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the factorials you mention don't have anything to do with probability - rather, they have to do with combinatorics.  This is because in this context, you are talking about *uniformly random* elements of some set - and so counting up the elements with a specific property is a necessary step of the process.

Factorials are important because $n!$ is the number of ways to list - in order - a set of $n$ objects that are distinguishable. Because of this, it also comes up in other arrangements - such as the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ (in an order or otherwise).  Further, many other combinatorial constructions can be carried out starting with these basic ideas of arrangements, and so they involve factorials as well.

You are absolutely right that *distinguishable* is a keyword that screams factorial; however, distinguishability of the objects is often implicit in the problem, rather than explicitly stated.  The big thing: look for any situation in which you are arranging objects in some way.

Comment: I've seen a question answered with factorial and nCr . So what's the difference between them? When should I use factorial and when should I switch to nCr? I know nPr is for when order matters.

Comment: Factorials serve two purposes, both stated above: the number of ways to order a set of $n$ objects is $n!$, and this makes it useful in other formulas. What you call "nCr" stands for _combinations_ - the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ distinguishable objects, where order doesn't matter. Contrast this with $nPr$, which is the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ distinguishable objects when order _does_ matter.

Comment: @MethodManX Also note that the formulas for "nCr" and "nPr" both involve factorials.

Comment: Okay so factorial is number of ways to arrange something and NPR and nCr is number of ways to choose something?

Comment: if the question says indistinguishable is it still factorial?

Comment: Factorials still come in to it, but not in this way. For instance, the number of ways to put $n$ indistinguishable balls in to $r$ boxes turns out to be $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ - or, in your notation, (n+r-1)Cr.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help buddy.